# Make an exact copy of a paragraph including all contents and properties?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to do an exact copy of one paragraph into another (I'm copying a template over to a new document for word-replacement). I'm doing this for paragraphs within a table cell, but I don't believe that is significant. The following code nearly works:

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
    XWPFParagraph np = newCell.addParagraph();
    np.getCTP().set(p.getCTP());
}
```

The problem is, while `np.getCTP().xmlText().equals(p.getCTP().xmlTest()` is true, `np.getText()` is blank while `p.getText()` has the contents of the paragraph. It seems like my paragraph doesn't know about the underlying change I made to the XML. This results in my output document containing the placeholder text because my code can't seem to see the contents of the paragraph any more in order to perform the replacement.

How can I make a perfect copy of a paragraph including all contents and properties?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be getting the job done. I'm not sure that the whole `cloneRun()` method couldn't be replaced by `nr.getCTR().set(r.getCTR());` but this seems better safe than sorry.

```
public static void cloneParagraph(XWPFParagraph clone, XWPFParagraph source) {
    CTPPr pPr = clone.getCTP().isSetPPr() ? clone.getCTP().getPPr() : clone.getCTP().addNewPPr();
    pPr.set(source.getCTP().getPPr());
    for (XWPFRun r : source.getRuns()) {
        XWPFRun nr = clone.createRun();
        cloneRun(nr, r);
    }
}

public static void cloneRun(XWPFRun clone, XWPFRun source) {
    CTRPr rPr = clone.getCTR().isSetRPr() ? clone.getCTR().getRPr() : clone.getCTR().addNewRPr();
    rPr.set(source.getCTR().getRPr());
    clone.setText(source.getText(0));
}
```

Comment: I'm using this code and I've seen that the spacing before lines was changed. Tried to use `np.setSpacingAfterLines(0);` after the cloning, without any results. Also, source text was in Times New Roman, while destination text resulted in Calibri.

Comment: @FranciscoBouza Without spending a lot of time on it, the only thing I can suggest is to look through the xml source of the docx file and see if you can figure out what is setting the font and line spacing and look for Poi functions to specifically address those properties. I believe a colleague of mine ran into that issue. I'll check to see if he ever got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public XWPFParagraph copyParagraph(int currentParagraphIndex)
    {
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = wordDocument.getParagraphs();

        //get whatever paragraph we're working with from the list
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = paragraphs.get(currentParagraphIndex);

        XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
        //inserts a blank paragraph before the original one
        paragraph.getDocument().insertNewParagraph(cursor);

        //make a fully parsed copy of the old paragraph
        XWPFParagraph newParagraph = new XWPFParagraph((CTP) paragraph.getCTP().copy(),wordDocument);

        //update the document with our now paragraph replacing the blank one with our new one and cause the document to reparse it. 
        //Not sure why, but any modification to the new paragraph must be performed prior to setting it. 
        wordDocument.setParagraph(newParagraph,currentParagraphIndex);

        return newParagraph;
    }
```