# How do you add an XDDF Chart to a specific paragraph run (i.e. a cell in a table)? POI 4.0.1

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I want to add a chart to a specific table cell within an XWPFDocument. I want the chart in the table cell so that I can ensure alignment with other elements I will add afterwards. So then,

- How do I create an XWPF/XDDF chart without adding it the document (e.g. without using document.createChart())?
- How do I take that chart and add it to a specific paragraph/run (e.g. the one that is created in the table cell)?

Already Tried:

1. Creating a chart mirroring the code found in *XWPFDocument.createChart()*
2. Using the *XWPFRun.addChart()* with the R*elationPart.getRelationship.getId()* I used from
3. Using *document.createChart()* after getting to the specific location of the table
4. Trying to make the chart -> XDDFDrawing and adding that to the run through *run.getCTR.addDrawing*... I don't think it goes this way?

/code example

```
// Create a document with some initial text
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
tmpRun.setText("text");
tmpRun.setFontSize(18);

// Try making the chart
// the same code as here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192804/how-do-i-add-a-second-line-with-a-second-axis-to-an-xddfchart-in-poi-4-0-1
try{
    String[] categories = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    Double[] values1 = new Double[]{1d,2d,3d,4d,5d,6d,7d,8d,9d};
    Double[] values2 = new Double[]{200d,300d,400d,500d,600d,700d,800d,900d,1000d};

    // create the chart
    // XWPFChart chart = document.createChart(7* Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 7*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);

    // Try to make a chart stand alone
    // using the same code as here, 
    // https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.java?view=markup

    int chartNumber = document.getCharts().size();
    POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart rp = document.createRelationship(XWPFRelation.CHART, XWPFFactory.getInstance(), chartNumber, false);
    XWPFChart chart = rp.getDocumentPart();
    chart.setChartIndex(chartNumber);
    chart.setChartBoundingBox(7* Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 7*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);
    document.getCharts().add(chart);


    // This stuff to make the chart is not part of the question
        // create data sources
        int numOfPoints = categories.length;
        String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
        String valuesDataRange1 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
        String valuesDataRange2 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 2, 2));
        XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange, 0);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values1, valuesDataRange1, 1);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values2, valuesDataRange2, 2);

        // first line chart
        XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
        XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
        chart.plot(data);

        solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

        // second line chart
        // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
        bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

        XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
        rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

        // set correct cross axis
        bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
        rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

        data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
        series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
        chart.plot(data);

        // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is one line series already
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

        solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.RED);


// End of extra stuff
// Back to question

    // Add the chart by relation id
    XWPFParagraph p2 = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun r2 = p2.createRun();
    r2.addChart(rp.getRelationship().getId());

    // Add a new run to try to add a new drawing?
    XWPFRun r3 = p2.createRun();
    CTDrawing drawing = r3.getCTR().addNewDrawing();
    ????

}catch(Exception e){}
```

When I add the chart via r2.addChart(), nothing shows up? So maybe I didn't create the chart correctly? Or I didn't add it to the run correctly?

Is it possible that the chart can be transformed to a drawing?

[This shows the XML I am trying to mimic (copied from the other image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCmF4.png)

1. Paragraph
2. Run
3. Drawing?
4. Chart?

[This is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyqxR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often `apache poi` makes it really hard to extend their code because of weird decisions about what methods are protected or private. In this case it lacks a method `public XWPFChart createChart(int width, int height, XWPFRun run)` in `XWPFDocument` since the existing methods always puts the chart into a new created run in a new created paragraph in document body. But simply extending `XWPFDocument` is nearly impossible because needed methods are protected or private.

Simplest approach I have found is to first put the chart in first paragraph of the document using `document.createChart()`. Then remove that first paragraph. The chart part remains (at least using `apache poi 4.1.0`). Then attach the chart part new at wanted text run. But even this is not as easy as it could be since `XWPFChart.attach` also is protected. So using `java.lang.reflect` is needed.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

public class CreateWordXDDFChartTwoLinesInTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument()) {

   // create the data
   String[] categories = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
   Double[] values1 = new Double[]{1d,2d,3d,4d,5d,6d,7d,8d,9d};
   Double[] values2 = new Double[]{200d,300d,400d,500d,600d,700d,800d,900d,1000d};

   // create the chart
   // this also puts the chart into a run in a new created paragraph
   XWPFChart chart = createChart(document, categories, values1, values2);
   // remove the first paragraph since we need the chart being elsewhere
   document.removeBodyElement(0);

   XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("First paragraph having first text run.");

   // create the table
   XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1,2);
   table.setWidth("100%");
   // create first run in first table cell
   paragraph = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   // attach the chart here
   java.lang.reflect.Method attach = XWPFChart.class.getDeclaredMethod("attach", String.class, XWPFRun.class);
   attach.setAccessible(true);
   attach.invoke(chart, document.getRelationId(chart), run);
   chart.setChartBoundingBox(7*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 7*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);

   // set text in second table cell
   paragraph = table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getParagraphArray(0);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("Other text goes in the 2");
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT);
   run.setText("nd");
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText(" cell.");

   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("Lorem ipsum...");

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordXDDFChartTwoLinesInTable.docx")) {
    document.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }

 private static XWPFChart createChart(XWPFDocument document, 
   String[] categories, Double[] values1, Double[] values2) throws Exception {

   // create the chart
   XWPFChart chart = document.createChart();

   // create data sources
   int numOfPoints = categories.length;
   String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
   String valuesDataRange1 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
   String valuesDataRange2 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 2, 2));
   XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange, 0);
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values1, valuesDataRange1, 1);
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values2, valuesDataRange2, 2);

   // first line chart
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
   XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
   chart.plot(data);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

   // second line chart
   // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
   bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

   XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

   // set correct cross axis
   bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
   rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

   data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
   chart.plot(data);

   // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is one line series already
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.RED);

   return chart;
 }

 private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
  line.setFillProperties(fill);
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setLineProperties(line);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! This works perfectly, thank you! java.lang.reflect.Method is a nice trick!

Comment: In case it is helpful for others, I also tried creating, duplicating, and then removing the paragraph, but I got stuck with the duplication part. I tried the clone methods here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112924/make-an-exact-copy-of-a-paragraph-including-all-contents-and-properties but the drawing was not duplicated. I even tried cloning every single element in the Run (inline, graphic, , graphicData, etc), but no luck there either. I'd duplicate Axel's pattern if I needed to do something like that in the future

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function to add an XWPFChart chart in an XWPFRun run. we can also extend the XWPFDocument with a custom java class and create a function with the access of protected variables which can be easy.

```
protected XWPFDocument addChartToRun(XWPFDocument document, XWPFChart oldChart, XWPFRun run) {
        try {
            //find number of charts available
            int chartNumber = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < document.getRelations().size(); i++) {
                if (document.getRelations().get(i) instanceof XWPFChart) {
                    chartNumber++;
                }
            }

            //creating new chart from oldChart
            POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart rp = document.createRelationship(
                    XWPFRelation.CHART, XWPFFactory.getInstance(), chartNumber + 1, false);
            XWPFChart chart = rp.getDocumentPart();
            chart.setChartIndex(chartNumber);
            Method attach = XWPFChart.class.getDeclaredMethod("attach", String.class, XWPFRun.class);
            attach.setAccessible(true);
            attach.invoke(chart, rp.getRelationship().getId(), run);
            chart.setChartBoundingBox(200, 200);


            // copy old chart style
            if (oldChart != null) {
                chart.getCTChartSpace().setSpPr(oldChart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr());
                chart.getCTChartSpace().setChart(oldChart.getCTChartSpace().getChart());
                chart.getChartSeries().addAll(oldChart.getChartSeries());
            } else {
                //oldChart not found
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }

            return document;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while copying chart...");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I have not tested this implementation, but it looks like it would work to copy a chart into a run.

Comment: yes. it is possible to copy a chart to a run with all its styles.